# OFHighScoreService was not declared in this scope

Tags: iphone, xcode, scope, openfeint

I have OpenFeint integrated, compiling and launching when my app launches. Following the OF website instructions of:

1. Add a leaderboard to your application from the Developer Portal.
2. Note the Unique Identifier of your new leaderboard.
3. 

```
  In your application, submit the player’s score like this

    [OFHighScoreService setHighScore: scoreGoesHere forLeaderboard:@"leaderboard_id_string" onSuccess:OFDelegate() onFailure:OFDelegate()];
```

When I call this:

```
[OFHighScoreService setHighScore:scores forLeaderboard:@"112033" onSuccess:OFDelegate() onFailure:OFDelegate()];
```

I get an error: 'OFHighScoreService' was not declared in this scope. I'm not sure what to do - I tried importing OFHighScore.h but that didn't work. Do I need to add a highscore delegate?

Comment: Doh. Had to include OFHighScoreService.h. In a rush and just saw OFHighScore. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh. Had to include OFHighScoreService.h. In a rush and just saw OFHighScore.